# Hibernate HQL Query to get parent + children based on childID

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, parent

I have an object with several @onetomany relationships, and I need to query for properties in the parent, as well as properties of the children. I can't seem to get it done.

For example, I need a query that lets me see the Parent objects where where the parent's name is "John" *and* the child's favorite color is blue. Hope that makes sense. The reason for the complication seems to be that children are in a list, not in a @onetoone relationship.

```
PARENT:
@Entity
@Table(name="Parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="parent_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="parent_gen", sequenceName="PARENT_SEQUENCE")
    private int parentID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    @JoinTable(name = "parent_to_child")
    private List<Child> childList;
    // and so forth

Child 
@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="child_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="child_gen", sequenceName="CHILD_SEQUENCE")
    private int childID;

    @Column(name="favoriteColor")
    private String favoriteColor;

    // and so forth
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select p from Parent p join p.childList c
    where p.name = 'John' and c.favoriteColor = 'blue'
```

This will return a `List<Parent>`.

You can look all this in the [hql reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: This seems to fetch the results as 2 distinct objects, parent in [0] and child in [1]. This might work, but I figured it would just return the "real" objects? I need to figure out how to fetch the parent and child out of the generic Object they are returned as... I'm getting there!

Comment: @user1454878 A select clause is needed for that. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This still shows every child object in the list no matter if favoriteColor is blue, red or white. Is it normal? Was it not supposed to only show child objects whose favoriceColor is blue?

Comment: @This select return parents, not childs. It will return any parent with a child with favoriteColor = 'blue', even if it has more childs with favoriteColor different that blue.

Comment: @Pablo can we do it using Criteria API somehow ?

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as follows:

```
from Parent as parent
    left join parent.childList as children
        with children.favoriteColor = 'blue'
where parent.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do--- parent "left join fetch" child with your condition.

"**left join fetch**" gives result in List< Parent>

Without Fetch it will be List where object[0] = parent and object[1] = child.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class Clients implements Serializable  {
  @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
      @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
       @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
        List<SmsNumbers> smsNumbers;
        }

 @Table(name="smsnumbers")
  public class SmsNumbers implements Serializable {
    @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
String number; //getter and setter
}
```

On the basis of child class i fetch the parent in unidirectional relation using the following criteria-

```
   Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    try{
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Clients.class);
    criteria.createAlias("smsNumbers", "child");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("child.number", phone).ignoreCase());
    Clients cli=(Clients) criteria.list().get(0);
    System.out.println(cli.getId());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL provides a special syntax that, in these cases, makes things easier and helps you to think in an Oriented Object way:

```
SELECT p FROM Parent P, IN (P.childList) C 
WHERE P.name='John' and C.favoriteColor='blue';
```

The operator IN iterates over lists, thus avoiding the need of using JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));
criteria.createAlias("childList", "child");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("child.favoriteColor", "Blue").ignoreCase());
```

You can try with criteria API also.